# Auto Populate Custom Field with Complex Value That Increase by One?

Tags: custom-field, functions, wp-query, automation

Can somebody help me to sort this?

I am using WP 3.5.2 and I have "Orders" post type where purchase_order custom field is located.

This is the sample of purchase order record:

POCOS20130051

**PO** - is prefix that is always the same

**CO** - first 2 letters of the site name - if site name is "Coca Cola" - CO will appear (if I change the name of the site, this will change too)

**S** - always the same

**2013** - current year

**0051** - number that increase by 1 when hit Add New Order. Must have 4 characters. If number is 1 then 0001 will appear.

Now....

I need this as a hook that will auto generate and auto populate my purchase_order custom filed.
PO number must be generated as a unique record.

Function has to count "published and drafted" **Order** post types and then to increase that number by one, so last part of PO number can be generated (0051).

For the reference, please take a look how this guy solved something similar
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491733/Auto-generated-sequence-number-in-SQL-Server

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need somewhere to globally store last order number. Preferable in table wp_options. Method `update_option` will help you. 
Then you need to make a function which will fires everytime when new order appears.

something like that:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'setOrderNumber');
function setOrderNumber($post_id) {

  $slug = 'orders'; // slug of your post_type called "Orders"

  if ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

  $counter = get_option( 'lastOrderCount' ); // example 0051
  $counter++; // returns 0052
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'purchase_order', 'POCOS'.date('Y').$counter);
  update_option( 'lastOrderCount', $counter ); // set the new number of order. 
}
```

I didn't checked this function, but I hope it works.

Comment: It returns only the first part: POCOS2013.

4 character number is missing at the end.

Comment: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/7595/l76c.jpg

Comment: I been thinking something.... I think that this will not work because of save_post action triggered. Why? Well, if client want to update order, and in a mean time new order is submited, PO number will be overwritten, and I don't need that. I think that it would be better if we could use default custom filed value that is generated via hook. What do you think?

Comment: at first: you need to set up first initial value for order number.
second thing: you need to add condition if custom field in order exists then do nothing.

Are you familiar with php or you need full working code for this ?

Comment: Yes please. Help me here if you can. I didn't solve this jet. I am not familiar with PHP.
I find out that I need something like IF NOT NULL do NOTHING, but that is all I can say.